# How many times is the print statement executed?

Tags: loops, for-loop, math, discrete-mathematics

```
For i:=1 to 200 do
    For j:=1 to 200 do
        For k:=1 to j-1 do
            Print "Hello"
```

How many times is the print statement executed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it, including a code attempt. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected from your code, what you got, and any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's 4,000,000 times.
200*200 for the 2 outer iterations- and then 200/2 for the (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)... iteration.

```
                              -----------------
For i:=1 to 200 do            ----------       |
    For j:=1 to 200 do        --        |      |  
        For k:=1 to j-1 do      |200/2* | 200* | 200
            Print "Hello"     --        |      |
                              ----------       | 
                              -----------------
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. Please do not guess in the answers--guesses belong in the comments. You really also should not answer a question that shows absolutely no work from the questioner.

Comment: This answer is correct. It's not well written only. Please @riki accept the edition

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia: This answer is *not* correct. I got the correct answer in two very different ways, and those ways agree. If the questioner provides the missing context I will be glad to give an answer with those two different ways.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I agree about the missing context by the questioner. I made a script in python with the pseudocode from above and It gives me almost 4M assuming it was my error. Maybe you are right, it's less than 4M

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia: Yes, the correct answer is a little less than four million. Your script is almost certainly correct.